# Installing kaleo-web source code in liferay

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, portlet, liferay-theme, spring-portlet-mvc

I have to deploy kaleo-web plugin from eclipse,it is showing invalid location, I have placed kaleo-web plugin in webs folder as it is after downloading, alternatively I have tried with deploying it from cmd prompt.As kaleo-web contains service.xml, so I have done ant build-service,it is showing build failed, can any one help regarding this?

```
D:\Migration-work-for_Liferay62\one-click62\plugins\webs\kaleo-web>ant build-ser
vice
Buildfile: D:\Migration-work-for_Liferay62\one-click62\plugins\webs\kaleo-web\bu
ild.xml

build-service:
    [mkdir] Created dir: D:\Migration-work-for_Liferay62\one-click62\plugins\web
s\kaleo-web\docroot\WEB-INF\classes
     [copy] Copying 24 files to D:\Migration-work-for_Liferay62\one-click62\plug
ins\webs\kaleo-web\docroot\WEB-INF\classes
     [copy] Copied 45 empty directories to 35 empty directories under D:\Migrati
on-work-for_Liferay62\one-click62\plugins\webs\kaleo-web\docroot\WEB-INF\classes

      [jar] Building MANIFEST-only jar: D:\Migration-work-for_Liferay62\one-clic
k62\plugins\webs\kaleo-web\build-service-classpath.jar
   [delete] Deleting: D:\Migration-work-for_Liferay62\one-click62\plugins\webs\k
aleo-web\build-service-classpath.jar.manifest
   [delete] Deleting: D:\Migration-work-for_Liferay62\one-click62\plugins\webs\k
aleo-web\build-service-classpath.jar
     [echo] Loading jar:file:/D:/Migration-work-for_Liferay62/one-click62/bundle
s/tomcat-7.0.42/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/portal-impl.jar!/system.properties
     [echo] Loading jar:file:/D:/Migration-work-for_Liferay62/one-click62/bundle
s/tomcat-7.0.42/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/portal-impl.jar!/portal.properties
     [echo] Loading file:/D:/Migration-work-for_Liferay62/one-click62/bundles/to
mcat-7.0.42/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes/portal-ext.properties
     [echo] Loading jar:file:/D:/Migration-work-for_Liferay62/one-click62/bundle
s/tomcat-7.0.42/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/portal-impl.jar!/com/liferay/portal/too
ls/dependencies/portal-tools.properties
     [echo] Building KaleoAction
     [echo] Building KaleoCondition
     [echo] Building KaleoDefinition
     [echo] Building KaleoInstance
     [echo] Building KaleoInstanceToken
     [echo] Building KaleoLog
     [echo] Building KaleoNode
     [echo] Building KaleoNotification
     [echo] Building KaleoNotificationRecipient
     [echo] Building KaleoTask
     [echo] Building KaleoTaskAssignment
     [echo] Building KaleoTaskAssignmentInstance
     [echo] Building KaleoTaskInstanceToken
     [echo] Building KaleoTimer
     [echo] Building KaleoTimerInstanceToken
     [echo] Building KaleoTransition
    [javac] Compiling 1 source file to D:\Migration-work-for_Liferay62\one-click
62\plugins\webs\kaleo-web\docroot\WEB-INF\service-classes
    [javac] ----------
    [javac] 1. ERROR in D:\Migration-work-for_Liferay62\one-click62\plugins\webs
\kaleo-web\docroot\WEB-INF\service\com\liferay\portal\workflow\kaleo\definition\
DurationScale.java (at line 17)
    [javac]     import com.liferay.compat.portal.kernel.scheduler.CronText;
    [javac]            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    [javac] The import com.liferay.compat cannot be resolved
    [javac] ----------
    [javac] 2. ERROR in D:\Migration-work-for_Liferay62\one-click62\plugins\webs
\kaleo-web\docroot\WEB-INF\service\com\liferay\portal\workflow\kaleo\definition\
DurationScale.java (at line 25)
    [javac]     DAY("day", CronText.DAILY_FREQUENCY),
    [javac]                ^^^^^^^^
    [javac] CronText cannot be resolved to a variable
    [javac] ----------
    [javac] 3. ERROR in D:\Migration-work-for_Liferay62\one-click62\plugins\webs
\kaleo-web\docroot\WEB-INF\service\com\liferay\portal\workflow\kaleo\definition\
DurationScale.java (at line 26)
    [javac]     HOUR("hour", CronText.HOURLY_FREQUENCY),
    [javac]                  ^^^^^^^^
    [javac] CronText cannot be resolved to a variable
    [javac] ----------
    [javac] 4. ERROR in D:\Migration-work-for_Liferay62\one-click62\plugins\webs
\kaleo-web\docroot\WEB-INF\service\com\liferay\portal\workflow\kaleo\definition\
DurationScale.java (at line 27)
    [javac]     MINUTE("minute", CronText.MINUTELY_FREQUENCY),
    [javac]                      ^^^^^^^^
    [javac] CronText cannot be resolved to a variable
    [javac] ----------
    [javac] 5. ERROR in D:\Migration-work-for_Liferay62\one-click62\plugins\webs
\kaleo-web\docroot\WEB-INF\service\com\liferay\portal\workflow\kaleo\definition\
DurationScale.java (at line 28)
    [javac]     MONTH("month", CronText.MONTHLY_FREQUENCY),
    [javac]                    ^^^^^^^^
    [javac] CronText cannot be resolved to a variable
    [javac] ----------
    [javac] 6. ERROR in D:\Migration-work-for_Liferay62\one-click62\plugins\webs
\kaleo-web\docroot\WEB-INF\service\com\liferay\portal\workflow\kaleo\definition\
DurationScale.java (at line 29)
    [javac]     SECOND("second", CronText.SECONDLY_FREQUENCY),
    [javac]                      ^^^^^^^^
    [javac] CronText cannot be resolved to a variable
    [javac] ----------
    [javac] 7. ERROR in D:\Migration-work-for_Liferay62\one-click62\plugins\webs
\kaleo-web\docroot\WEB-INF\service\com\liferay\portal\workflow\kaleo\definition\
DurationScale.java (at line 30)
    [javac]     WEEK("week", CronText.WEEKLY_FREQUENCY),
    [javac]                  ^^^^^^^^
    [javac] CronText cannot be resolved to a variable
    [javac] ----------
    [javac] 8. ERROR in D:\Migration-work-for_Liferay62\one-click62\plugins\webs
\kaleo-web\docroot\WEB-INF\service\com\liferay\portal\workflow\kaleo\definition\
DurationScale.java (at line 31)
    [javac]     YEAR("year", CronText.YEARLY_FREQUENCY);
    [javac]                  ^^^^^^^^
    [javac] CronText cannot be resolved to a variable
    [javac] ----------
    [javac] 8 problems (8 errors)

BUILD FAILED
D:\Migration-work-for_Liferay62\one-click62\plugins\build-common-plugin.xml:262:
 The following error occurred while executing this line:
D:\Migration-work-for_Liferay62\one-click62\plugins\build-common.xml:634: Compil
e failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Total time: 42 seconds
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed the package in the class

```
D:\Migration-work-for_Liferay62\one-click62\plugins\webs
\kaleo-web\docroot\WEB-INF\service\com\liferay\portal\workflow\kaleo\definition\
DurationScale.java
```

From `com.liferay.compat.portal.kernel.scheduler.CronText` to `com.liferay.portal.kernel.scheduler.CronText` and then performed ant build-service and the ant deploy, then kaleo-web successfully deployed.

Reference: https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/58130766